# How to generate a matched set of random SNPs based on distance to gene and MAF?

Tags: genetics

I have a list of SNPs (rs#) and I would like to generate a matched set of random SNPs based on distance to gene and MAF so I can use it to calibrate background expectations in SNP-based enrichment analysis. 
I've tried SNPsnap but I keep getting an internal server error (code 500)

Can someone suggest other tools or help me please? I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: FYI, SNPsnap has worked for me now.

Comment: Please add your comment as an answer to this question so we know it is resolved.